Zero initial condition with a non-linear system of first-order differential equations
Suppose some system of first-order non-linear differential equations
$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = A x(t) + B y(t) + C z^4(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}y(t) = D x(t) + E y^2(t) + F z(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}z(t) = G x(t) + H y(t) + I z^3(t)
$
There is no source term.
If the initial conditions are zeroes $x(t=0)=0$, $y(t=0)=0$, $z(t=0)=0$, is only the only solution the trivial one $x(t)=y(t)=z(t)=0$?
If so, why is this?
Question: Given some system of nonlinear first-order ODEs without a source term and with zeroes for the initial condition is the trivial solution always the only one?

Yes, the solution is unique. This follow directly from the Picard–Lindelöf theorem. The ODE can be written as $\dot{\mathbf x}(t) = \mathbf f(\mathbf x)$ with $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf f$ a continuously differentiable function. Since $\mathbf f$ is $C^1$, it is also locally Lipschitz. So you can find a neighborhood $D$ of $\mathbf 0 \in \mathbb R^3$, where $\mathbf f$ is Lipschitz on $D$. The Picard–Lindelöf theorem states solutions of the ODE on $D$ are unique. This implies any local solution that satisfies the zero initial conditions must equal the zero solution. And since the Lipschitz constant doesn't depend on $t$, you can extend the result to show that the only possible solution is $\mathbf x(t) = \mathbf 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.
